# Align ([r][l][c]) AutoNiceMatrix

Tags: stix, nicematrix

Good Afternnon,

I need to left-align the  `a_{i}{j}`s of this NiceMatrix:

```
\[A = \pAutoNiceMatrix{10-10}{a_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}} \]
```

How Can I do? (If serves, I use `stix`-package).

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

I have written a new version of `nicematrix` (v. 5.17 of 2021-07-01) which allows the keys `l`, `r` and `c` for the command `\pAutoNiceMatrix` and the similar ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[A = \pAutoNiceMatrix[r]{10-10}{a_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[A = \pAutoNiceMatrix{10-10}{\Block[r]{}{a_{\arabic{iRow},\arabic{jCol}}}}\]

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Perfect Thank you. Best Regards

Comment: Sorry, This Code doesn't actually function

Comment: I use Overleaf. Is this the problem?

Comment: Overleaf has not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: But if I do `\pAutoNiceArray[t]{l}{...}` why doesn't it function?? And how could do it functioned?? Thx

Comment: However I already have the `nicematrix.sty`...

Comment: As of now, this is not implemented. I will try to write a new version of `nicematrix` with the keys `l` and `r` for the command `\pAutoNiceMatrix`.

Comment: You probably don't have the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty`. You need at least version 5.6 of 2020-11-08.

Comment: Ok. How do I do to load that version on LaTeX Overleaf (I mean your site: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`)? Thx.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126951/discussion-between-f-pantigny-and-puck).